# Можно ли назначить формулу для столбца в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть ли в MySQL такая функция, как например в excel: задать одному столбцу какую-нибудь формулу, чтобы каждая ячейка в этом столбце = сумме других ячеек в строке? Причем, чтобы при изменении значений в строке сумма менялась автоматически. Или нужно все это делать вручную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранить в базе данных избыточные данные не принято. А колонка, всегда имеющая некое значение, зависящее от других колонок той же таблицы - явная избыточность. Для того, что бы можно было не писать каждый раз требуемые вычисления и при этом не хранить в базе избыточные данные придуманы VIEW.

Например, создадим *view* "добавляющее" колонку с суммой колонок A и B:

```
create or replace view MyView
as
select T.*, A + B as AB
  from TableX T
;
```

После этого мы можем при выборке данных использовать эту *view* вместо таблицы для получения данных:

```
select *
  from MyView
 where AB > 10;
```

В результате запроса мы получим данные из таблицы TableX в которых сумма колонок A и B больше 10. В выводе будет и сама колонка 'AB' содержащая сумму.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно решить эту задачу через триггер. Например, путь имеется таблица `tbl` с тремя столбцами `one`, `two`, `other`. Можно создать два триггера на вставку и обновление данных, например, помещая в столбец `other` сумму двух других столбцов (столбцу `other` при этом можно не назначать значение)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER addTbl
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.other = NEW.one + NEW.two;
END//
CREATE TRIGGER updateTbl
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.other = NEW.one + NEW.two;
END//
```

Так как в составе триггера мы используем разделитель точка с запятой, то в примере выше при помощи команды `DELIMITER` меняется признак окончания запроса на // (в GUI-средах это либо не требуется, либо для разделителя предназначено отдельно поле).